# Invalid Iterator Fix

Tags: iterator

So, looking for advice on how to fix a situation or maybe a better way to program it.

I'm using iteration to build a complicated string from key:value pairs in an unordered_map.  To make this work, I'm iterating through the map to find specific items, then sending a search term to an outside function to create the string.  The outside function uses its own iterator to search the same unordered_map for the passed search term, then creates the string, then erases the entries that it referenced.  The problem, I believe, is that although the outside function's iterator is still valid because it called the erase function, the iterators in the main function are now invalidated and throwing an out of range error.  Is there a way to reset the iterators or send them to the next valid key:value pair when they become invalidated in order to avoid the error?

The code is a mess (mostly because I'm still discovering C++) and it might be possible to use recursion to accomplish this, but I wasn't able to get recursion to work correctly.

I can post the code, but without understanding the inputs and required outputs, it's likely not going to help explain anything, so for now, I'll just leave the question as-is: is there a way to "re-validate" invalidated iterators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by redefining each of the iterators once the scope of control returned back to them.  For the last iterator (in the outside function) that deleted individual key:value pairs from the unordered_map, I used:

```
if (it != map.end()) it = map.erase(it);
```

This forces the iterator to move to the next valid key:value pair after the erasure.

That worked for the end of the line, but didn't work once control was returned to each of the previous iterators.  In those case, the iterators were invalidated when the outside function erased a key:value pair.  So as control returned to an iterator, I included the following line before it looped back for increment:

```
if (it != map.end()) it = map.begin();
```

It seems to have resolved all of the issues, though I'm sure there's a better way to handle it.